# after several iterations, program jumps to an if statement inside loop (python)

Tags: python, loops

The program continuously asks for string values and evaluates if they are equal or not until the user, after asked by prompt:

> Do you want to continue computations? (Yes or No)

stops saying "yes"

Given that there's already a first element, here's the while loop:

```
while inputswitch=="yes":   

    a=input("Enter name: ")
    alist.append(a)

    for i in range (0, len(alist)-1, 1):

        if a.lower()==alist[i].lower():

            alist.pop(len(alist)-1)

            print("Match found")

            inputswitch=input("Do you want to continue computations? (Yes or No) ").lower()


        if (i==len(alist)-2) and (a.lower()!=alist[i].lower()):

            print("Not equal")

            inputswitch=input("Do you want to continue computations? (Yes or No) ").lower()
```

The problem begins after having 5 elements in the list (named alist) and inputting a 6th element identical to elements with index<=2. The program runs both if statements under the loop.

To demonstrate, after having a list like this:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

I input the same exact  C like the third element. The first if statement does run and it prints:

```
"Match found"
```

But after the prompt

> Do you want to continue computations? (Yes or No)

It jumps to the second if statement regardless of the answer to that prompt; it doesn't ask for a new input and it prints:

```
"Not equal"
```

And asks this again

> Do you want to continue computations? (Yes or No)

I'm lost. There seems to be a problem with the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use variable `inputswitch`. After

```
inputswitch=input("Do you want to continue computations? (Yes or No) ").lower()
```

You should add a conditional branch depending on what `inputswitch` is:

```
if inputswitch == "yes":
    # do something (continue computations)
elif inputswitch == "no":
    # do something else (maybe stop computations)
```